# incorporate a timestamp into ajax load data endless scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've written a Javascript function that loads paginated content onto a page as you scroll to the bottom. The goal of this function is to increment the page number as you scroll and add that specific page number to the content already displayed, like Facebook does.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).scroll(function() {
         var pagenumber = document.getElementById("pagenumber");
         var results_box = document.getElementById("results_box");
         var combo = pagenumber.innerHTML.split("|");
         var pn = parseInt(combo[0]);
         var last = parseInt(combo[1]);
         results_box.innerHTML = "";
         if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -      $(window).height()) {
             // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
             results_box.innerHTML = "Loading...";
             if (last != 1) {
                 if (pn < last) {
                     request_page(pn + 1);
                 } else if (pn == last) {
                     pagenumber.innerHTML = pn + 1 + "|" + last;
                     request_page(last);
                 } else {
                     results_box.innerHTML = "No More Content available";
                 }
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

the ajax "loading..." code not fire but when it randomly does it might load just two pages or duplicate some. My conjecture is that is has to do with the lack of a timestamp on each request for a new page.
 The request_page function is fired once before the page is loaded, to display the first page of code, and the pagination "next" button when clicked accurately adds new content to the page,so my question is, how would i incorporate a timestamp into this function to effectively load data onto a page?

For clarity there is a div that displays the page number you're on out of total pages ex. 1 | 3 , the "last" variable is the last page ( 3 ) and the "pn" page number variable is the current page (1)